# C++ std::system_error usage with common catch std::exception block

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

`std::system_error` handles exception with associated error code. Is it possible using common catch block to get std::system_error exception message and it's code? Like this

```
try{
    // code generating exception
} catch (const std::exception& ex){ // catch all std::exception based exceptions
    logger.log() << ex.what();      // get message and error code
                                    // if exception type is system_error     
}
```

Is the only way is to catch directly `std::system_error` type and get its code before base exception type catching? What is the best approach to use std::system_error widely?

Comment: Hmm, may be you could try with a `dynamic_cast` check, but what bothers you with simply catching `std::system_error`?

Comment: @πάντα it's okay, I'm just interesting if more concise way exists. I prefer not to use `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Why not catching `system_error` explicitly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What is the best approach to use std::system_error widely?

The best approach in my opinion, is to catch the exception directly.

```
catch (const std::system_error& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    std::cout << e.code() << '\n';
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n'; 
}
```

> Is the only way is to catch directly std::system_error type and get its code before base exception type catching?

It's technically not the only way. It's the obvious and idiomatic way. You *can* use `dynamic_cast`.

```
catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    auto se = dynamic_cast<const std::system_error*>(&e);
    if(se != nullptr)
        std::cout << se->code() << '\n';
}
```

But you mention in the comment that you prefer not to use `dynamic_cast`. It's possible to avoid that too, but not in any way that has any advantages.

Note that even if you *can* do things in non obvious ways, it doesn't mean that you *should*.